# how to translate ITEM using the Vue i18n library

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-i18n

I have an element that displays text this way

```
 <div class="body-1 mt-4">{{ item.titleDesc }}</div>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text class="project-description">
              <v-layout row fill-height v-for="(desc, index) of item.description" :key="index">
                <v-flex
                  xs4
                  class="text-xs-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase caption px-2 py-1"
                >{{ desc.name }}</v-flex>
                <v-flex xs8 class="text-lowercase desc-text px-2 py-1">{{ desc.text }}</v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
```

{{ item.titleDesc }}, {{ desc.name }}, {{ desc.text }}
I have jason

```
 "items": [
    {

      "titleDesc": "same text",
       "description": [
        {
          "name": "same text", 
          "text": "same text "
        },
```

and I have json with translations

```
{"en-US":{"same text":"same text","same text":"same text"}
```

there is a loop that checks the keys

```
Object.keys(fileJsonObject).forEach((languagesJson) => {

              messages[languagesJson] = Object.assign(messages[languagesJson] ? messages[languagesJson] : {}, fileJsonObject[languagesJson])

            })
```

I need items to be passed through my jason with translations and then displayed.How to do it? Please help, I'm completely new to this

Comment: Sorry, could you make it more clear what exactly you have and what needs to be done.

Comment: I need to, for example, item.titleDesc, before displaying the text, pass it through the library and search for the necessary translation and then display it. The original jason has a title, and so on, that should be output. And in Jason the library is just an array of words and phrases. And in order not to enter every phrase, you need to display item, which must first go through the library and find the necessary translation for phrases

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `{{ desc.text }}` with `{{ $t(desc.text) }}`

See the [docs](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html)

If you have Vue-i18n [setup correctly](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#html) it should just work....